# Column chart in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to create a vertical column chart in Apex 4.2. The width of each column should be set to 1 or 2 so that it will look like a line and not like column. How can this be achieved in Apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, I don't have 4.2 any more, but - have a look at the Chart Settings. At the bottom of the list, there should be "Custom XML" (or something like that) which is disabled by default.

You can enable it (by clicking the checkbox, I think) and Apex will let you modify it.

In there, you'll see different options; read it carefully, perhaps you'll find the setting you're looking for. Or, if you know *how* to exactly do it, you can type it directly.

Note that - if you change your mind and switch the Custom XML off, Apex will restore chart default settings (at least, I think so) and everything you changed so far will be lost. So - create a backup copy of your custom XML, just in case.